# Why Prettier doesn't follow my .prettierrc.json file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-eslint

Edited: I'm trying to set my custom rules for prettierrc.json and it shows another value in the output. It happens with every rules that i tried to change

Thats my .prettierrc.json

```json
{
  "useTabs": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false, //// my custom value
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "endOfLine": "auto"
}
```

And it shows in the console

```
["INFO" - 16:33:14] Formatting c:\Users\User\Desktop\repos\boludeces\.prettierrc.json
["INFO" - 16:33:14] Using config file at 'c:\Users\User\Desktop\repos\boludeces\.prettierrc.json'
["INFO" - 16:33:14] Using ignore file (if present) at c:\Users\User\Desktop\repos\boludeces\.prettierignore
["INFO" - 16:33:14] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "json"
}
["INFO" - 16:33:14] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 16:33:14] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "c:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\repos\\boludeces\\.prettierrc.json",
  "parser": "json",
  "useTabs": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true, // the output value
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "endOfLine": "auto"
}
["INFO" - 16:33:14] Formatting completed in 12.8338ms.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Given that the output explicitly says it detected that local configuration, it's unclear what you think the problem is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i couldnt understand why i write singleQuote false then i found other value in the output :/. It happens if i try to change other values. It doesnt respect my custom values

Comment: Did you try to restart VS Code?

Comment: @thorn̈ yes and it works, the point is.... why i need to restart my IDE when i change a value from prettier? is it okay?

Comment: Kind of okay I guess. Those values aren't supposed to change often, so Prettier caches resolved configurations files instead of constantly re-resolving them.

Comment: Restarting VS Code solved the issue for me also